# Using group by on two fields and count in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my mysql db that has two columns: group and subgroup. See below.

```
 group, subGroup
 grp-A, sub-A
 grp-A, sub-A
 grp-A, sub-B      
 grp-B, sub-A
 grp-B, sub-B
 grp-B, sub-B
```

I am trying to get the number of records for each unique couple group/subGroup.

This is what I expect:

```
group, subGroup, count
grp-A, sub-A, 2
grp-A, sub-B, 1
grp-B, sub-A, 1
grp-B, sub-B, 2
```

After reading some posts I tried several sql queries using group by, count(), but I do not manage to get the expected result. How can I fix this?

Comment: i wanted another case, count of sugroups for each group so this is the query SELECT a, b, COUNT(distinct b) FROM tbl GROUP BY a

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I think you're looking for: `SELECT a, b, COUNT(a) FROM tbl GROUP BY a, b`

Comment: Hello Corbinb. Thank you very much. it is working. I did what you are suggesting but insted of group by a, b I did group by a and b. Thanks again

Comment: `a and b` looks like a statement to MySQL (not actually sure if it would be a syntax error or if it would group on the 0 or 1 return -- I would assume a syntax error, especially for varchar fields).  To group on multiple columns, you just use a comma.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! .. The issue with me was I wasn't able to phrase my question and spent a lot of time googling finally landed here for a simple and dot solution.

Comment: Instead of the count I needed the entire record details. For example, grpA has to 2 subgroups: subA and subB, so I need to retrieve the entire record for each of the subgroups. Can anyone please help me. @Corbin

Comment: i wanted count of sugroups for each group so this is the query SELECT a, b, COUNT(distinct b) FROM tbl GROUP BY a

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT group,subGroup,COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY group,subgroup
```

Comment: Instead of the count I needed the entire record details. For example, grpA has to 2 subgroups: subA and subB, so I need to retrieve the entire record for each of the subgroups. Can anyone please help me. @user1127214

Answer (score 8):

You must group both columns, group and sub-group, then use the aggregate function `COUNT()`.

```
SELECT
  group, subgroup, COUNT(*)
FROM
  groups
GROUP BY
  group, subgroup
```

Comment: Seems a typo to me group!= groupName

Comment: Instead of the count I needed the entire record details. For example, grpA has to 2 subgroups: subA and subB, so I need to retrieve the entire record for each of the subgroups. Can anyone please help me. @farzane

Answer (score 0):

It is easily possible. You need to GROUP BY multi fields. Those are on 'mainGroup' and then 'subGroup'

```
select mainGroup, subGroup, Count(mainGroup) from table group by mainGroup, subGroup
```