# Average Temperature Grouped by Serial number with day intervals

Tags: mysql

So, I'm a bit stuck trying to calculate averages in a MySQL query.  What I'm trying to do is read the data from two tables, one of which is small and has entries describing the room, serial number, elevation, and other data about a sensor.  The other table contains the recordings of the temperature output for each serial number.  Here's some sample data for each table.

```
+------------------+-------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+
| serial           | room  | rack | elevation | type    | system | threshold |
+------------------+-------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2B211 | 5    |         5 | DS18S20 | test   |        68 |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2B211 | 5    |         5 | DS18S20 | test   |        68 |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2B211 | 5    |         5 | DS18S20 | test   |        68 |
+------------------+-------+------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+


+------------------+---------------------+---------+
| serial           | dtg                 | reading |
+------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:30:28 |    98.6 |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:28 |    73.4 |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:28 |    79.7 |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:30:38 |    98.6 |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:38 |    73.4 |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:38 |    79.7 |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:30:48 |    98.6 |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:48 |    73.4 |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:48 |    79.7 |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:30:58 |    98.6 |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:58 |    73.4 |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:30:58 |    79.7 |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:31:08 |    98.6 |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:31:08 |    73.4 |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:31:08 |    79.7 |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:31:18 |    98.6 |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:31:18 |    73.4 |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:31:18 |    79.7 |
+------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

I have an SQL query that can pull the data a format it into a table that I'm then converting into JSON and passing to a web browser for visualizing.  It looks similar to this, although a little different because I'm using a stored procedure to modify the timing interval.

```
SELECT sensor_data.serial, sensor_data.dtg, sensor_data.reading, sensor.elevation,sensor.room, sensor.system FROM sensor_data, sensor WHERE sensor.serial = sensor_data.serial AND sensor_data.dtg BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AND NOW();
```

The result looks like this

```
+------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
| serial           | dtg                 | reading | elevation | room  | system |
+------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:34:39 |    98.6 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:34:49 |    98.6 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:34:59 |    98.6 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:35:09 |    98.6 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:35:19 |    98.6 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 2D0008017075F210 | 2013-08-02 12:35:29 |    98.6 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:34:39 |    73.4 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:34:49 |    73.4 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:34:59 |    73.4 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:35:09 |    73.4 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:35:19 |    73.4 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 1D00080170496D10 | 2013-08-02 12:35:29 |    73.4 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:34:39 |    79.7 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:34:49 |    79.7 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:34:59 |    79.7 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:35:09 |    79.7 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:35:19 |    79.7 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
| 380008017037ED10 | 2013-08-02 12:35:29 |    79.7 |         5 | 2B211 | test   |
+------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

What I would like to do is create a statement that could pull say 5 days of records and return a result set that has a row for each day containing all the above information with the temperatures averaged for each day.  I know that the data at the moment all has the same temperature, but it's in a test environment where there isn't really any variation.  Not being a DBA I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you should take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10380990/589985).  It's got a good example of grouping by multiple columns.  You'll want to use `AVG` instead of `COUNT` in your case, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to format the datetime to strip off the time component, and then group by it:

```
SELECT 
    sensor.serial,
    date_format(sensor_data.dtg, '%m/%Y/%d') as dtg_day,
    sensor.elevation,
    sensor.room, 
    sensor.system,
    avg(sensor_data.reading),
    count(1) reading_count
FROM 
    sensor
    NATURAL JOIN sensor_data
GROUP BY
    sensor.serial,
    dtg_day,
    sensor.elevation,
    sensor.room, 
    sensor.system
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5919f/20/0)

Comment: Wow, thank you so very much.  I'd been trying to find an answer to that for a couple of hours and was getting nowhere fast.

Comment: I wanted to say thank you again as well,  that was pretty easy to make into prepared statements so I could pull by hour/day/month.  One quick question that I had about though, is there a way to rename the dtg_day column to just dtg?  I modified the "as dtg_day" to "as dtg"  but it spits out all of them.

Comment: To do that, you have to replace `dtg_day` in the GROUP BY clause with `date_format(sensor_data.dtg, '%m/%Y/%d')`.  If you just change `dtg_day` to `dtg`, that will refer to the original dtg column.