# How to "distinct" count in a window function in Postgresl?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I've a simple table -

```
--------------------------------------------------
| srcip | dstip | dstport            
--------------------------------------------------
| X     | A     | 80
--------------------------------------------------
| X     | A     | 443
--------------------------------------------------
| X     | B     | 8080
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want output like this-

```
--------------------------------------------------
| srcip | dstip | count            
--------------------------------------------------
| X     | A     | 2
--------------------------------------------------
| X     | B     | 1
--------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to use `COUNT(distinct dstport) OVER(PARTITION BY dstip,dstport) as count` in window function but getting error `WINDOW definition is not supported`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using group by on two fields and count in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380990/using-group-by-on-two-fields-and-count-in-sql)

Comment: You are requesting a window function, but the sample results look more like simple aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as you've written the question, the value is always "1" (or perhaps `NULL`).  The code is counting `dstport` and you are partitioning by the value.  So, there can be only one.

You can do this with two levels of window functions.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*,
       sum( (seqnum = 1)::int ) as count_distinct
from (select . . . ,
             row_number() over (partition by dstip order by dstport) as seqnum
      from . . .
     ) t
```

Comment: the only answer that uses a window function

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way is to use count with two column is as below:

```
SELECT srcip , dstip , COUNT(dstip) FROM tbl GROUP BY srcip , dstip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with a as(
        Select 'X' srcip,'A' dstip, 80 dstport
        Union
        Select 'X','A',443
        Union
        Select 'X','B',8080
    )

select srcip,dstip,count(dstip)  from a
group by srcip,dstip
order by dstip;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WPFMWI80812)