# How do you SELECT all rows while counting the number of instances?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT MID, COUNT(*)
FROM [Main].[Product].[Report]
GROUP BY MID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

This gives me:

```
312391933 2
231313111 2
```

But I want:

```
312391933 2 2020/02/01 true
312391933 2 2019/02/02 false
231313111 2 2020/01/01 true
231313111 2 2019/01/01 false
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried joining the table to itself and using a subquery, but nothing seems to work. All the rows come from the same table.

Comment: Sample data, and expected result, will help us help you. We have no idea where the extra data in your expect results is coming from.

Comment: `2020/02/01` must be in another date or datetime or varchar or??  column? and group by that also.

Comment: They're all in the same table and it's a datetime.

Comment: so so many duplicates of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381027/125981

Comment: It's not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window functions.  They can be lifesavers and are well worth your time to get comfortable with them.

**Example**

```
with cte as(
    Select MID
          ,Cnt = sum(1) over (partition by MID)
          ,SomeDateCol
          ,SomeTrueFalseCol
     From  YourTable
)
Select *
 From  cte
 Where Cnt>1
```

Comment: I need the sum to be greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: @caesar We can nest it in a subquery or a CTE  ... See Update